# Test-Flight crash: AVFAudio: AVAE_RaiseException(NSString*, ...) + 52

Tags: avfoundation, core-audio

I create a app which record audio and play in swift
everything work fine in my real device but put in test-flight to test with other device it crash.

Here my code in swift 5.5

'''

```
func startRecording() {
    if recognitionTask != nil {
        recognitionTask?.cancel()
        recognitionTask = nil
    }
    
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .spokenAudio, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
    }
    
    let bus = 0
    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    
    let inputFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: bus)
    let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1, interleaved: true)!
    let converter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputFormat, to: outputFormat)!
    
    inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 1024, format: inputFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
        var newBufferAvailable = true
        let inputCallback: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { inNumPackets, outStatus in
            if newBufferAvailable {
                outStatus.pointee = .haveData
                newBufferAvailable = false
                return buffer
            } else {
                outStatus.pointee = .noDataNow
                return nil
            }
        }
        
        let convertedBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: outputFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(outputFormat.sampleRate) * buffer.frameLength / AVAudioFrameCount(buffer.format.sampleRate))!
        
        var error: NSError?
        let _ = converter.convert(to: convertedBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputCallback)
        self.recognitionRequest?.append(convertedBuffer)
    }
    
    audioEngine.prepare()
    try audioEngine.start()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.speechRecognize()
    }
}
```

'''

and the crash
'''

```
AVFAudio: AVAE_RaiseException(NSString*, ...) + 52
```

'''

Comment: What is the backtrace for the crash?

Comment: i don't get it from test-flight